# Ajax call on WordPress causes long TTFB - how to improve?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

**CONTEXT**

I'm experiencing very long Time To First Byte on a [WordPress page](http://coachingourselves.com/modules-english/) that uses Ajax to filter/load resources.

Basically, the Ajax call tells a PHP file what filter has been applied on the front end, the PHP file gets the relevant values from SQL to construct a long HTML string and then the PHP file returns this long HTML string through Ajax. This PHP file looks something like this:

[image]

There is quite a lot of HTML that is being returned by the Ajax call (~300KB) but I wouldn't think that's the issue.

**QUESTION**

How can I find what is causing this long TTFB? Assuming the basic sequence of steps can't be changed, what can be done to improve TTFB?

Comment: Are you using NewRelic or a similar performance measuring tool? If not, look into it. Looks as though you're using PHPStorm, that's good as PHPStorm has built-in debugging. Step through your code and see what's taking the most time. That's going to be the easiest way to do it other than NewRelic or another performance measuring / reporting tool.